# Wso2 identity server load balanced setup refresh token issue

Tags: load-balancing, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Refer the raised jira issue in below link .
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4633

Any solutions for solving this issue.., 
We tried to temperorly solve this issue by editing sqlscripts.java file by downloading it from github, compiled it and tried to pack in same jar file (using winzip, as jar files are zip finally).

As part of the change we had removed TOKEN_SCOPE column from relevant sql query, but still error in log describes 'invalid column TOKEN_SCOPE'
Kindly suggest to make any further changes or share me the jar file.
I am using wso2 identity server v5.1.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be already reported in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4532

This issue is already fixed in 5.2.0 which will be released soon. You can try the 5.2.0 beta from https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.2.0-beta

You can find the fix from the PR in the jira I have pointed.

Comment: This did't worked, refer below logs ..same issue
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'TOKEN_SCOPE'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
.        org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.validateRefreshToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:791)
        ... 60 more

Comment: changing SQLQueries.java would require all dependent classes to be recompiled.

Comment: Did you try with the beta pack provided above

Comment: Seems to be this issue is different from the one I have pointed. There is another issue with Sql server query. See the PR https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/pull/75